# Woocommerce skip checkout for free products

Tags: woocommerce

I'm building webpage on WP and Woocommerce - I would like to skip cart and also checkout page for free products (or products which ID-s I can specify). These products are free and virtual (no payment needed, no shipping needed). The webpage is only used by registered users - so all the customer info is present.

The result I would like to have is that if you press ORDER button on product page - the order is done and customer is redirected to Thank-You page.

BR,
Kaspar

Comment: So what have you tried in order to accomplish that?

Comment: Honestly I haven't came up with any of working solutions. In theory it would work, if there was a button on the product page that adds the product to cart and confirms checkout at the same time...

Comment: If someone could help me with some coding.

If there was function that would do so on the checkout page:

Check if cart need payment - if no (it means cart is free), then fire action that is fired when customer presses place order button. If yes , (cart need payment), then do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I applied the same concept, but found a major issue when processing order on the checkout; fields were still required.

The primary issue was processing the order via AJAX ( was using `is_ajax()` ), and even though it was on the checkout page, it wasn't returning as true. It's possible there was a recent change, or it could be the site's environment (theme).

Here are some of the conditional tags: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Seeing how things change, the answer can be edited here, but the original concept is located at: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-simplify-free-woocommerce-checkout/

```
function wc_free_checkout_fields() {
    // Bail we're not at checkout, or if we're at checkout OR AJAX (payment process) but payment is needed.
    if ( function_exists( 'is_checkout' ) && ( ! ( is_checkout() || is_ajax() ) || ( ( is_checkout() || is_ajax() ) && WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove coupon forms since it's irrelevant with a free cart?
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );

    // Remove the "Additional Info" order notes.
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false' );

    // Unset the fields we don't want in a free checkout.
    function wc_unset_unwanted_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
        // Add or remove billing fields you do not want.
        // @link http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-2
        $billing_keys = array(
            'billing_company',
            'billing_phone',
            'billing_address_1',
            'billing_address_2',
            'billing_city',
            'billing_postcode',
            'billing_country',
            'billing_state',
        );

        // For each unwanted billing key, unset.
        foreach( $billing_keys as $key ) {
            unset( $fields['billing'][$key] );
        }

        return $fields;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'wc_unset_unwanted_checkout_fields' );

    // A tiny CSS tweak for the account fields; this is optional.
    function wc_print_custom_css() {
        ?>
        <style>
            .create-account {
                margin-top: 6em;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'wc_print_custom_css' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wc_free_checkout_fields' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the checkout has no cost with the WC()->cart->needs_payment() check.
see this for more info:
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-simplify-free-woocommerce-checkout/

Comment: Thanks! During research for solution I have read this article too, but I (actually my customer) would like to skip the second button click on the checkout...

Comment: Do you see these 2 links: 1. wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout 2. chrislema.com/woocommerce-no-products-page

Comment: The first one skips cart, which I already use - it doesn't help me to skip the checkout.

Comment: The second one teaches how to use woocommerce without product page - you still need to use checkout. In my case - I have some custom fields on product page, which customer needs to fill in, so I can't skip the product page.